# Pass multiple arguments and iterables to Python's multiprocessing.Pool.map

Tags: python

I've read many posts regarding to passing multiple arguments or passing iterables to Python's `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, but none of these seems to discuss the most general case, i.e, passing multiple arguments AND multiple iterables. In code, it should look like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(func, args=(), iterables=()) # passing multiple args and iterables
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

When using [Pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) and related functions, your worker function must take a single value: one item of work. If an item of work must contain multiple values, create an appropriate data structure to hold them (e.g. tuple, list, dict, or instance of a user-defined class).

Similarly, `Pool.map()` processes a single iterable. However, iterables can be chained, zipped, or combined in various ways. See the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html) package for some examples.